# Protection from zip bombs with python3's zlib.uncompress

Tags: gzip, python-3.6, zlib

I need to uncompress data using `zlib.uncompress` from source that may or may not be trusted. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html#zlib.error) for zlib says the `decompress` method raises `zlib.error` in case any error occurs, but can this on it's own protect from zip bombs? (i.e. should I add catch for e.g. `MemoryError`?)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `zlib.decompressobj` instead to protect against bombs.